# Fedora 29 KDE edition stuck in login loop on fresh install

Tags: fedora, login

Recently moved from Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon edition to Fedora 29 KDE edition keeping the home partition.

Problem was that I couldn't progress past the login screen, I was stuck in a login loop.

Comment: Unrelated update: Moving to Fedora Cinnamon edition, KDE is way too bugy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem like this in the past with Linux Mint, at that time I tried doing the following

`rm ~/.Xauthority && rm ~/.ICEauthority`

as suggested by a user on [this thread](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=274362) which worked, **unfortunately, it did not work this time.** Which I understand because its a completely different OS.

Feel free to try it though, it *could* work for you.

Instead, what did work for me, was the following:

1. Login via `tty`
2. Navigate to `/`
3. Run `ls -lZ /home`
4. If the output of the previous command is anything other than `unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t`, then following the rest of the steps should solve the login loop problem, otherwise, this solution is unlikely to work for you, sorry.
5. Run `sudo restorecon -R /home`
6. Logout of `tty` and try to login again the normal way

[thanks to](https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?281548-selinux-change-directory-failed-permission-denied&p=1587276#post1587276)